# Limit of quotients of recursively defined sequences?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

I'm trying to find the fixed point of a dynamical system. I have two recursively defined sequences $x_n,y_n$
$$x_n = a\left(\frac{1}{1+\lambda}\right)^n + q\left(1-a\left(\frac{1}{1+\lambda}\right)^n\right) x_{n-1}$$
$$y_n = b\left(\frac{1}{1+\lambda}\right)^n + q\left(1-b\left(\frac{1}{1+\lambda}\right)^n\right) y_{n-1}$$ where $a,b > 0$ and $\lambda,q \in (0,1)$. Individually, both sequences $x_n,y_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. Any ideas on an expression or an approach to finding $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{x_n}{y_n}$$

I initially thought this limit was $\frac{a}{b}$ after solving for $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{(1+\lambda)^n x_n}{(1+\lambda)^n y_n}$, but after visualizing the sequence I found this limit depended on $q$ as well.

I also thought about using Stolz–Cesàro Theorem and analyzing $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x_n-x_{n-1}}{y_n-y_{n-1}}$, but that didn't seem to get me anywhere. Any help would be appreciated

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let $u_n := f^n x_n,$ where $f := 1 + \lambda.$ Then
$$u_n = a  + q (1 - f^{-n}) f u_{n - 1} = a + q(1 - f^{-n})f a + q^2 (1 - f^{-n})(1 - f^{- n + 1})f^2 u_{n - 2},$$
so by proceeding inductively we deduce that
$$u_n = a\sum_{0 \leq k \leq n - 1} (q f)^k \prod_{1 \leq l \leq k}(1 - f^{-n + l - 1}) + q^{n - 1} f^{n - 1} \prod_{2 \leq l \leq n}(1 - f^{-l}) u_1 = \\
q^{n - 1} f^{n - 1} \big( u_1 \prod_{2 \leq l \leq n}(1 - f^{-l}) + a \sum_{0 \leq k \leq n - 1} (q f)^{- k} \prod_{k + 2 \leq l \leq n} (1 - f^{-l}) \big).$$
Note that the rightmost term corresponds to the partial series of a converging series (since all the products are less than $1$), so it converges to say $S$ as $n \to \infty.$ Mutatis mutandi, denoting $v_n := f^n y_n,$ we also obtain
$$v_n = q^{n - 1} f^{n - 1} \big( v_1 \prod_{2 \leq l \leq n}(1 - f^{-l}) + b \sum_{0 \leq k \leq n - 1} (q f)^{- k} \prod_{k + 2 \leq l \leq n} (1 - f^{-l}) \big).$$
Using the standard logarithm inequality $\log(1 + x) \leq x,$ we obtain
$$\log \prod_{2 \leq l}(1 - f^{-l}) \leq \sum_{2 \leq l} - f^{-l} = - \frac{1}{\lambda^2 + \lambda},$$
so $\prod_{2 \leq l}(1 - f^{-l}) \to P$ as $n \to \infty.$ It follows that
$$\frac{x_n}{y_n} = \frac{u_n}{v_n} = \frac{u_1 \prod_{2 \leq l \leq n}(1 - f^{-l}) + a \sum_{0 \leq k \leq n - 1} (q f)^{- k} \prod_{k + 2 \leq l \leq n} (1 - f^{-l})}{v_1 \prod_{2 \leq l \leq n}(1 - f^{-l}) + b \sum_{0 \leq k \leq n - 1} (q f)^{- k} \prod_{k + 2 \leq l \leq n} (1 - f^{-l})} \to \frac{P (\lambda+ 1) x_1 + a S}{P (\lambda+ 1) y_1 + b S}.$$
Having acquired all this information, I suspect a closed form result for this limit would be rather hard to obtain. Nonetheless, I hope this helps. :)

Comment: Very interesting, thank you. Can you explain which term you are referring to with S?